# Capture Sound from Mic/Headphone and trigger action at perticular frequency

Tags: audio, capture, signal-processing, frequency-analysis

I am using .NET 3.5.

I need to Capture Sound from Mic/Headphone and trigger action at particular (not exact)  frequency (**Need to perform some action when player hits ball with stick while playing golf**).

So,
1. How to capture sound from Mic/Headphone using .NET 3.5?
2. Trigger action at particular (not exact) frequency?

Any ideas?

Comment: Found one good sample at: http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/.

Its exactly what I want. But written in WPF. Does anyone have same sample (measuring frequency while recording) written in .NET 3.5 (without WFP)?

Answer (score 3):

For (2) I suggest the [Goertzel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm), which is very simple to implement and will allow you to detect energy in a narrow range of frequencies.